# How did they shoot the bowling ball scene in The Big Lebowski?

Tags: effects, cinematography, the-big-lebowski

The Big Lebowski (1998) features a number of surreal dream sequences in it. In one of them, the Dude is plastered by a bowling ball and obtains the viewpoint of a bowling ball as it rolls down the lane. How did they make this shot?

Comment: I always thought that it was a camera in a bowling ball or some other device that rolls down the lane... :)

Answer (score 12):

From Quora By [Matt Burwood](https://www.quora.com/profile/Matt-Burwood):

> To achieve the point-of-view of a rolling bowling ball the Coen brothers mounted a camera "on something like a barbecue spit", according to Ethan, and then dollied it along the lane. The challenge for them was figuring out the relative speeds of the forward motion and the rotating motion. CGI was used to create the vantage point of the thumb hole in the bowling ball.
>
> Source: [The Big Lebowski - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Lebowski)

They used RC cars to film the shots where the camera is following the ball.

<sup>[source](https://www.quora.com/How-did-they-do-the-inside-the-bowling-ball-shot-in-The-Big-Lebowski)</sup>